# Does new versions of google map's javascript versions work on JavaFx-WebView

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx

I am trying to load **google map** on **JavaFx-WebView**, and it doesn't show anything except background color of html body that i have coded on html file.
Also i tried some examples on Google search, all the result were older. None of it works.
**My Java version is "1.8.0_121"**

*I wrote a html file & run it. It loaded google maps successfully.
Then i load the html file to webview using webEngine.load("path") method.
it doesn't show anything except backgound color.*

**After that I tried
http://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX**

- runs ClusteredMainApp.java (put my google api key)
- consoles outputs  are:
- "hier"
- "clustererimages/m"
- "Hide directions called"
- "loadMapLibrary"
- "loadMapLibrary done"
- "initMap"
- "LatLong: (47.606189, -122.33584200000001)"
- "netscape.javascript.JSException: Error: The Google Maps JavaScript
  API does not support this browser. (undefined,0)"

> *Also i couldn't find any solutions for this error*

**Html File**

CSS:

```
#map_canvas { height: 100%; background-color: blue; }
```

javascript:

```
function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.39822, -121.9643936);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    navigationControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    backgroundColor: "#666970"
                };

                document.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                document.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

}

html:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
   </body>
```

JavaFX:

```
public class WebMap extends Application {
 
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create web engine and view
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("WebMap.html").toString());
        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web Map");
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView,1000,700, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // show stage
        stage.show();
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps API dropped support for older browsers which started causing the "The Google Maps JavaScript API does not support this browser." error. Look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions.

The library you are using is using version 3.exp (experimental).

Running on a newer Java version will fix this (for now).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `GMapsFX` you can download the sample code from your link.

If you look closer you will see the lib got an class `GoogleMapView` and this contains is own `WebView`

some code from `GMapsFX`

```
public class GoogleMapView extends AnchorPane {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleMapView.class);

protected static final String GOOGLE_MAPS_API_LINK = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp";
protected static final String GOOGLE_MAPS_API_VERSION = "3.exp";

private boolean usingCustomHtml;

protected String language;
protected final String region;
protected String key;
protected WebView webview; <-- Own WebView
protected JavaFxWebEngine webengine;
protected boolean initialized = false;
protected final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
protected final List<MapComponentInitializedListener> mapInitializedListeners = new ArrayList<>();
protected final List<MapReadyListener> mapReadyListeners = new ArrayList<>();
protected GoogleMap map;
protected DirectionsPane direc;
protected boolean disableDoubleClick = false;
```

So if you want to use the lib you should not create your own `WebView`.

You could start with the Sample

```
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.event.GMapMouseEvent;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.event.UIEventType;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class LatLongFXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label latitudeLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label longitudeLabel;

    @FXML
    private GoogleMapView googleMapView;

    private GoogleMap map;

    private DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.00000");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        googleMapView.addMapInitializedListener(() -> configureMap());
    }

    protected void configureMap() {
        MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();

        mapOptions.center(new LatLong(47.6097, -122.3331))
                .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
                .zoom(9);
        map = googleMapView.createMap(mapOptions, false);

        map.addMouseEventHandler(UIEventType.click, (GMapMouseEvent event) -> {
            LatLong latLong = event.getLatLong();
            latitudeLabel.setText(formatter.format(latLong.getLatitude()));
            longitudeLabel.setText(formatter.format(latLong.getLongitude()));
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It throws error on `map = googleMapView.createMap(mapOptions, false);` saying **Error: The Google Maps JavaScript API does not support this browser.**

Comment: Show stacktrace

Comment: Maybe it is just a matter of setting a proper user agent on the web engine.

Comment: I think you are missing the source `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

Comment: Unable to capture stactrance. it comes from executing native method

Comment: Unable to capture stactrance. it comes from executing native method on GoogleMapView class
-> class GoogleMapView
-> method public GoogleMap createMap(MapOptions mapOptions, boolean withDirectionsPanel)
-> line map = internal_createMap(mapOptions);

Comment: -> runs to class com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.JavascriptObject
-> method:73 protected JavascriptObject(String type, Object... args)
-> line:76 runtime.execute("var " + variableName + " = " + runtime.getConstructor(type, args));

Comment: -> runs to class com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.JavascriptRuntime
-> method:62 public JSObject execute(String command) <-- command = "var GoogleMap2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),MapOptions0)"

Comment: -> runs to class com.sun.webkit.WebPage
-> method:1471 public Object executeScript(long frameID, String script) throws JSException
-> line:1482 return twkExecuteScript(frameID, script); <-- It goes to under this line of code. after that throws exception. Exception is not visible in NetbeasOutput. I debuged through this. it shows a stactrace

Comment: I think you are missing the data. Because the lib is loading its own `maps.html` you can find it in the resources/com/lynden/gmapsfx/html